# Is it better practice to store arrays or strings in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a mongo database that contains mostly strings, although some fields do need to be arrays.  As I can only index one array in a Mongo collection, is it better to store the arrays of strings as comma delineated strings, and convert them in my API, or leave them as strings?  If that makes sense?

for example if I had a collection of balloons that looked something like so:

```
{
"_id": {
    "1"
},
"balloonName": "bubbles",
"balloonColours": [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green"
],
"balloonPurchases":[
    {
        "_id": {
            "1a"
        },
        "customer": "Dave",
    }
]
}
```

Rubbish example, but, my thoughts are that, it would be better to store balloonColours as a string in the db and convert between string and array in the API, as then I can index that field as well as my balloonPurchases field, but I'm not that well versed in Mongo and wondered if this is something that will cause problems, or could be considered bad practice.  My collection is rather large, so would converting strings to arrays and vice versa make searches a lot longer than if they're checking fields that aren't indexed, etc?

I hope that's not too unclear.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB supports the following:

- Storing array values for fields
- Indexing on fields which has array values.

Only limitation mentioned is that, if you are creating compound indexes, then you cannot have two fields such that both of them have array values.

Please refer to the link below:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Coming to your exact question about which is a better practice, if you need an array in the document, it would make sense to store it as an array in MongoDB and avoid unnecessary conversions in your code. MongoDB supports an array, so that it can be utilized.